# Cursor not moving to secondary display in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get the cursor to go to the secondary display, but it is staying in primary display.

I have referred to the following page, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen

Why doesn't the cursor go to the secondary display?

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win

app.on('ready', () => {
  let displays = electron.screen.getAllDisplays()
  let externalDisplay = displays.find((display) => {
    return display.bounds.x !== 0 || display.bounds.y !== 0
  })

  if (externalDisplay) {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
      x: externalDisplay.bounds.x + 50,
      y: externalDisplay.bounds.y + 50
    })
    // win.loadURL('https://github.com');

    secondaryWindow = window.open("secondary.html" + (debug ? "?debug=1" : ""), 'Secondary Display', 'height=100%,width=100%,top=0,left=0,fullscreen=1,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0' );
  }
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `window.open`? I get `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when running your code

Comment: it will send the page into  `secondary display`  (`if (externalDisplay) {}`)

Comment: I don't understand though, `window` is not defined there, your code won't work.

Comment: it is javascript `window` like `document`

Comment: Not in the Main process it isn't, it doesn't exist there.

Comment: the code is not in `main.js` it is in some other page

Comment: But if it is in the Renderer process, you would have to use `Electron.remote`

Comment: how can you please go ahead with that?

Comment: I'm sorry, does this code work at all? If so, what is required to duplicate the issue that you're having?

Comment: basically what i'm doing `if(externalDisplay){window.open("secondary.html" + (debug ? "?debug=1" : ""), 'Secondary Display', 'height='100%',width='100% ',top='0',left='0',fullscreen=1,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0' );}`   that is what i'm doing

Comment: Ok, but how are you loading this code in a Renderer process? Obviously I'm trying to get information from you that is not already in your question. Repeating information that is in your question is not going to help me help you.

Comment: don't know it works for me ,  code is written by someone else i'm maintaining it

Comment: Also, that line doesn't work at all, I just get a syntax error that there's a bracket missing.

Comment: i have minimize that line by removing some variables here is original one `window.open("secondary.html" + (debug ? "?debug=1" : ""), 'TelePrompter Output', 'height=' + (primaryDisplay.workArea.height-50) + ',width=' + (primaryDisplay.workArea.width-50) + ',top='+ (primaryDisplay.workArea.y+50) +',left=' + (primaryDisplay.workArea.x+50) + ',fullscreen=1,status=0,location=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0');`

Comment: Alright, that helps get rid of that as a potential problem. I still need to know how you're loading this renderer process in order to replicate the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to at least include your `main.js` file that should preferably show how this Renderer process is loaded, and if possible your `package.json`

Comment: "Why doesn't the cursor go to the secondary display?" Because 1. you don't try to move it at all 2. electron won't move your mouse, just create a window where you tell it.

Answer (score 2):

1. try to only create new BrowserWindow in main process
2. create a new window on where your want to position it, but electron won't move system cursor
3. checkout [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs), it will do the work.